# file uploader for joomla 2.5 admin panel

Tags: php, joomla

I need help on how to implement file uploading code inside Joomla Admin panel Component.
I need file uploading at joomla CSS editor page from where admin can upload new css.
i had checked some link like http://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_file_uploader_in_your_component
but not able to understand. Any help please it will be appreciated.

Thanks,
Manpreet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are in luck cause I have just finished building a free component for a file uploader using SWFUpload. You can download it from the link below.

http://joomjunk.co.uk/products/component-home/swfupload.html

I made this component as simple as possible for Joomla 2.5 so people could easily integrate it into their own components. I hope this is what you are looking for and should you need help, please feel free to ask.

Comment: the link u mentioned above i am able to open it.Page remains blank after i open it.

Comment: i need to integrate it with CSS editing module how i can do this. Please help

Comment: @manpreet ah ok you wanted to edit a css file. well these are the files that I used in my shoutbox component to edit the css and save it in the backend. http://www.fileden.com/files/2012/6/11/3314934/css_edit.zip

Comment: also, the link I sent you to the component in my answer should work. Works for me and others

Comment: @Loadder Thanks ! a ton Sir, Well i am saying that i want to add swfuploader in Joomla Css editor. Mean wehn we open Joomla CSS editor uploading will be on same page.

Comment: @Loadder One more question i need same functionality as of CSS editor for Javascript editor. Flow will be link this when client click on Javascript Link a list of JS files shown on page. when we click on it we are able to append it and save also we need to upload new Javascript file. Please help.

Comment: Moreover the above Css ediote link you sent me that zip file do not have complete files link no installtion XML file and other config XML file etc.

Comment: yes the css_edit.zip i sent you is not a component, it only contains the necessary files for the css editor. If you want, you can send me your component and I will add it for you

Comment: please read above comments i need javascript editor my CSS editor is working fine sir

Comment: what I send you isnt just for css file, you can use it for any files. You just need to change the file location and it will show the code for it which you can then change and save. If you would like to send me your component I will try and integrate it for you if you want

Comment: well i need your help on it please give me idea about that i am enclosing a link please check it. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10979110/javascript-and-css-editor-in-joomla) this is what i need exactly.

Comment: @manpreet: I have given you 2 links to my component and code for the editor AND also offered to integrate it in your component....I can't really offer much more than this

Comment: i will send you component as soon as i finished it

Comment: can you give me your mail id. where i can send you component for JSS editing.

Comment: lodder15@hotmail.co.uk  >> so did you want the script to upload a css file or edit it?

Comment: i will tell you breif case on email.

Comment: I had sent u email check it please.